# Hide application in the OnBackButtonPressed event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have 2 pages. LoginPage and ListPage.

In the LoginPage I ask for the credentials and the stores.

Then I see a list of information in ListPage.

What I want to get is that when I press the back button and capture the OnBackButtonPressed event, I want the application to hide and not return to the LoginPage page.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: after Login, just replace your App's MainPage with ListPage instead of navigating to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using NavigationPage you should directly be setting the MainPage for Navigation if you do not want to go back:

```
Application.Current.MainPage= new ListPage();
```

Or in the existing flow, you can close the current window in onBackPressed:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
```

Or if you want to kill the process you can

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```